# Copying the format of a range in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, format, copy

I have a google sheet from which I am able to copy the values of a certain range (A12:H60) to a new spreadsheet. The range values are copied to a new spreadsheet but not the format of the range.
What I would like is to also copy the format of that certain range along with the values.
I am using a script that was provided to me by google's help communities, since I am not familiar with programming and I don't know how to change it to achieve what I want.
The script code I am using is:

```
'use strict';

/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user opens
* the spreadsheet.
*
* Adds a menu item to start copyValuesToNewSpreadsheet().
*
* @param {Object} e The onOpen() event object.
*/
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Δημιουργία φύλλου')
    .addItem('Δημιουργία αντιγράφου βαθμολογιών', 'copyValuesToNewSpreadsheet')
    .addToUi();
}

/**
* Makes a values only copy of a range in the spreadsheet and
* puts the new spreadsheet in a folder.
*/
function copyValuesToNewSpreadsheet() {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 2 June 2023
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/218958735
  try {
    const folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('ΒΑΘΜΟΛΟΓΙΕΣ').next();
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    const values = sheet.getRange('A12:H60').getValues();
    const ssName = sheet.getRange('K22').getDisplayValue();
    const ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create(ssName);
    ssNew.getRange('A1')
      .offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length)
      .setValues(values);
    const url = DriveApp
      .getFileById(ssNew.getId())
      .moveTo(folder)
      .getUrl();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`Οι βαθμολογίες αντιγράφηκαν στο φύλλο '${ssName}' στην διεύθυνση ${url}.`);
  } catch (error) {
    showAndThrow_(error);
  }
}

/**
* Shows error.message in a pop-up and throws the error.
*
* @param {Error} error The error to show and throw.
*/
function showAndThrow_(error) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 April 2020
  var stackCodeLines = String(error.stack).match(/\d+:/);
  if (stackCodeLines) {
    var codeLine = stackCodeLines.join(', ').slice(0, -1);
  } else {
    codeLine = error.stack;
  }
  showMessage_(error.message + ' Code line: ' + codeLine, 30);
  throw error;
}

/**
* Shows a message in a pop-up.
*
* @param {String} message The message to show.
* @param {Number} timeoutSeconds Optional. The number of seconds before the message goes away. Defaults to 5.
*/
function showMessage_(message, timeoutSeconds) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 April 2020
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(message, 'copyValuesToNewSpreadsheet', timeoutSeconds || 5);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Copy the sheet the copy the range and then delete the sheet that you just copied.